# How to execute an iteration multiple times if multiple conditions are true?

Tags: php

I have an "if" statement like this:

```
if( (first condition) || (second condition) || (third condition) ){

//line of code

}
```

If all 3 conditions are met,i want the line of code to run 3 times.If just 2 conditions are met,it must run 2 times,and so on.

This syntax its also good:

```
if(){}elseif(){}elseif(){}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

true will get evaluated to 1 and false to 0 in this:

```
$qty = (first condition) + (second condition) + (third condition);
```

Meaning `$qty` will contain the number of iterations desired.

So, you execute your command, like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$qty; $i++) {
  //Your line of code you want to execute, for example:
  echo $i, "\n";
}
```

No *explicit* `if-else` expressions needed.

Comment: mind = blown. I would have never come up with that one! Great

Comment: i understand your explanation,but since i am pretty new to programming,i dont know how to translate this,can you give me an example with if statement?

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement.  I'll edit to show executing the command that many times.

Comment: my code has to run,just when a condition is passed,where i should introduce it?

Comment: The condition is hidden, I guess.  In the calculation of `$qty`, it is basically saying `if the condition is true, then add 1; else 0` and it does it for all 3 conditions.  So, if 2 are true, then it adds `1 + 0 + 1` (or whatever patterns of 1's and 0's match).  Try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could first count numbers of execution and then use a loop:

```
$times = 0;
if (first condition) ++$times;
if (second condition) ++$times;
if (third condition) ++$times;

for (... 1 .. $times ...) do_your_thing();
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if conditions are short-circuit, that mean if the condition in front of other conditions is satisfied, the later ones will never get execute.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

So in your case, I think you should refactor the code in other approach, Jeremy Miller's answer seem to be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Here the count variable grab that how many conditions are true.
And the for loop will execute the code equals to that number of counts($count).

```
    $count = 0 ;
    if( first condition ){

        $count++;

    }
    if( second condition ){

        $count++;

    }
    if( third condition ){

        $count++;

    }
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        //line of code
    }
```

Comment: isnt possible with a single if?

Comment: i mean with "if" , i have to use just "if" , but if its possible just one,not three

Answer (score 1):

You can take to one variable all conditions values .after that run with the `loop`.As I think that is the short and best way.